# HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode does not escape double quote

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode function to pass value from viewbag to javascript variable in razor view, i noticed that single quote is escaped correctly but double quote is escaped by encoding it in html as `&quot;`

As per documentation it says it will escape single and double quote but actually its not.

in my view bag i have following code

```
ViewBag.UserID = "corp\\shyam\" O'Hern";
```

but in my razor view

```
var user = "@HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(ViewBag.UserID)"
```

i get following

```
"corp\shyam&quot; O'Hern"
```

how to fix this issue , dont want to get `&quot;` in javascript and it should work in all browser.